# Change output variable PHP fputcsv

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli

I'm outputting SQL data into a CSV file and want to make the data more user readable. Currently field `terminal_id` returns various integers and I want to translate it into more user readable data.

In the different rows I have integers from 1-10 in this field. I essentially want it to output as a simple text string in the CSV file dependent on what the integer is. So for instance, instead of outputting `3` in the CSV file (just a random example), I need it to output `New York`.

I have a separate table called `terminal` that has columns `id` and `name`. `name` is what I actually want outputting to the CSV file rather than `terminal_id`.

The column in table `terminalcashcollectionrecord` that has the `3` in it is `terminal_id`. This is the correlating data in table `terminal` that also has column `name` in it.

Here's the code a snippet of that specific code:

```
//query the database
$query = 'SELECT terminaltime, terminal_id, amount, terminaltime FROM terminalcashcollectionrecord';

if ($rows = mysqli_query($link, $query))
{
    // loop over the rows, outputting them
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
    {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
```

Comment: You need other tables like one with `id = 3` and `value = New York` and then join it with the proper column from  `terminaltime`.

Comment: So I actually have a separate table with this data. How would I go about joining it?

Comment: Which column in `terminaltime` has a `3` that needs to be New York and what are the column names in the other table?

Comment: I have a separate table called `terminal` that has columns `id` and `name` in it. `name` is what I actually want outputting to the csv file rather than `terminal_id`

Comment: To clarify, the column in table `terminalcashcollectionrecord` that has the `3` in it is `terminal_id` . This is the correlating data in table `terminal` that also has column `name` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should select `terminaltime` and `amount` from `terminalcashcollectionrecord` and `name` from `terminal` where `terminal_id` equals `id`. You had `terminaltime` listed twice so I removed the second one:

```
SELECT a.terminaltime, b.name, a.amount
    FROM terminalcashcollectionrecord a
    LEFT JOIN terminal b
    ON a.terminal_id = b.id
```

See [MySQL JOIN Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)